# Joining 3 tables in Symfony Propel Database ORM

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I'm building a job portal.
I'm using **symfony 1.1** framework which uses **Propel** database engine. I have three tables such as **user**, **job** and **job_applied**. user table has **uid** , job table has **jid** and job_applied has **uid** and **jid** . I need to get **job title, description, position** of job table according to **uid** and **jid** of job_applied table.

Comment: are you having to use symfony 1.1 for legacy reasons?  if you don't have to use 1.1, you should upgrade to 1.4.  symfony is no longer supporting anything older than 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(JobAppliedPeer::JID, JobPeer::JID);
$c->addJoin(JobAppliedPeer::UID, UserPeer::UID);
$c->add (whatever other criteria you need);

$apps = JobAppliedPeer::doSelect($c);

for ($apps as $app) {
 $jt = $app->getJob()->getJobTitle();
}
```

etc.

You may need to adjust this a bit because of your column names: I always use a  column name like 'job_id' for foreign keys like this, and then Propel automatically generates accessor methods 'getJob' and 'getJobId'.

Comment: In Symfony 1.4 this will do a database query for *every* iteration. You can see the queries in `log/frontend_dev.log`.